# iTextSharp : Cannot attach PageEvent on a PdfSmartCopy writer

Tags: events, itext, pdf-writer

This code using ItextSharp 5.5.10:

```
 var msOutput = new MemoryStream();
 var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 20);
 var writer = new PdfSmartCopy(document, msOutput);
 writer.PageEvent = new MyHeaderFooterEvents();
```

Throws "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object." when assigning the "writer.PageEvent" (also fails when doing a parameterless new Document()).

When this code works perfectly:

```
 var outputStream = new MemoryStream();
 var document = new Document(PageSize.A4, leftMargin, rightMargin, topMargin, bottomMargin);
 var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, outputStream);
 writer.PageEvent = new MyHeaderFooterEvents();
```

Any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Pdf[Smart]Copy` classes are intended for read-only usage. It's documented in the raw source code:

```
/// Setting page events isn't possible with Pdf(Smart)Copy.
/// Use the PageStamp class if you want to add content to copied pages.
```

Note to the iText development team - if [XML Documentation Comments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) using the `<summary>` tag are used instead of the current style, comments will show up in Visual Studio [IntelliSense](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcw1s69b.aspx).